# Have grid size depend on the largest content in the the column

Tags: html, css

Im facing an issue - Im trying to have my css grid be either 1 or 2 columns while maintaining the width of these two columns.

Eg i want the grid to take up as much space as the columns but nothing beyond that.
Heres an example of what im dealing with:

html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>text text text text text texttext text text text text text text </p>
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">dummydummy</div>
    <div class="item">dummmy</div>
    <div class="item">dummummy</div>
    <div class="item">dummydmy</div>
    <div class="item">du</div>
    <div class="item">dummydummy</div>
    <div class="item">dummy</div>
    <div class="item">dummydummy</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: left;
  
}
```

When the columns collapse into 1 (1fr) i want the grid to take up the minimum amount of space needed to hold that one item.
Does anyone know how i can do this?